# Get path of Special folders using Excel VBA in MAC

Tags: excel, vba, macos, outlook

I need to convert an Excel range into a CSV file.

My macOS: Version 13.5
Excel Version: Microsoft-365 (16.75.2)

I am following code, in this [link](https://www.macexcel.com/examples/filesandfolders/specialfolders/), written by Ron de Bruin.

```vb
Sub Save_Range_As_CSV_On_Mac()
    'Ron de Bruin, 27-April-2023
    'Save first as xlsx and the second time as csv seems to be the solution to fix the problem on the Mac
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim SaveFolder As String

    'Turn off ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts
    'Note: ScreenUpdating is not working correct on this moment in Mac Excel
    'We hope they fix it so I leave the code in this macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Range that you want to copy
    Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B3")

    'Create destination workbook with one sheet
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(1)

    'Paste the range inside thisnew workbook
    Rng.Copy
    wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Set the folder where you want to save the csv file, Desktop now.
    SaveFolder = MacScript("return posix path of (path to desktop folder) as string")
   
    'Save the workbook with the name MyCSV2 first as xlsx and then as csv file
    wb.SaveAs SaveFolder & "MyCSV2.csv", FileFormat:=51  'xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs SaveFolder & "MyCSV2.csv", FileFormat:=6  'xlCSV

    'Close the destination workbook
    wb.Close False

    'Turn on ScreenUpdating and DisplayAlerts
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I get an error in my MAC.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, MacScript inline AppleScript functionality was deprecated in 2016, and is disallowed by macOS 13. AppleScript is now called by this function in VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/office-mac/applescripttask however...

On macOS, using the HOME environment variable will get you to the correct folder without using AppleScript:

```
SaveFolder = Environ("HOME") & "/Desktop"
```